# How to load data from an URL in a grid in Extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an url in initComponent by: `this.myStore.getProxy().url = MY_URI +  record.data.id;`, where record is my selected record.

As a result from the **GET** url I get the following in Chrome's Network Response :

```
 {
     "result": {
        "id": "15",
        "height": "600",
        "width": "600",
        "squares": [{
            "id": 25,
            "height": 50,
            "width": 50
        }, {
            "id": 26,
            "height": 50,
            "width": 50
        }]
    }
}
```

Currently in the grid when: `store: this.myStore` and `dataIndex: 'id' or 'dataIndex: 'height' or ' dataIndex: 'width'` I don't get the values of the squares object, but the other ones, for example the *Height* column displays *600* and **not** *50*.

How can I display the squares' information in the grid?

Thank you.

Comment: How exactly do you want to display the squares information in the grid? Some data in a separate column? Or maybe in a row expander?

Comment: @scebotari66, for example :

columns: [
{ text: 'Square',  dataIndex: 'id' },
{ text: 'Height',  dataIndex: 'height' },
{ text: 'Width',  dataIndex: 'width' }
]

Comment: Does setting the proxy reader's `rootProperty` config to "squares" solve your problem?

Comment: @scebotari66, as a newbie in Sencha, I found some ideas about this problem when searching for 'how to load nested data in a grid', anyways, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `reader#rootProperty` to `'result.squares'`

Example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'squareStore',
    fields: ['id', 'height', 'width'],
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data1.json', // your url here
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'result.squares'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Square',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('squareStore'),
    columns: [{
        text: 'id',
        dataIndex: 'id'
    }, {
        text: 'Height',
        dataIndex: 'height',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Width',
        dataIndex: 'width'
    }],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/236t